# Exibir ProgressRing durante carregamento de dados

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid

Tenho um `ProgressRing`que deve ser exibido enquanto uma lista de contas é carregada num `DataGrid`:

```xml
<Grid>
    <ProgressRing x:Name="CarregamentoDeContas" />

    <controls:DataGrid
        x:Name="DataGridDeContas"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Contas}" />
</Grid>
```

code-behind:

```cs
    private List<Conta> Contas;

    private void ObterListaDeContas()
    {
        try
        {
            CarregamentoDeContas.IsActive = true;
            Contas = ListaDeContas.ObterContas();
        }
        finally
        {
            CarregamentoDeContas.IsActive = false;
        }
    }

    public ContasPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        ObterListaDeContas();
    }
```

Ao executar o aplicativo, os dados são carregados, mas o ProgressRing não é exibido. O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Joao, fui ver um exemplo de uso e achei um que seta a visibilidade do ProgressRing: ```CarregamentoDeContas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;```

Comment: @RodrigoTognin, obrigado pelo comentário. Coloquei o snippet dentro do `try` e ele trouxe o erro CS0176 O membro "Visibility.Visible" não pode ser acessado com uma referência de instância; qualifique-o com um nome de tipo. Setei a propriedade no controle, o que remove o erro, mas ainda não exibe o `ProgressRing`.

Comment: Joao, eu vi o exemplo nesse site: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xaml/xaml_progressring.htm - De repente você possa dar uma olhada e ver se tem alguma coisa faltando.

Comment: Achei outra coisa aqui João. Adicione essa biblioteca no seu projeto: ```using Windows.UI.Xaml;```

Comment: A biblioteca já está incluída, @RodrigoTognin. E o exemplo é o mesmo que há no Windows Community Toolkit Sample App. Passo a crer que o problema está no `try`; creio que se coloca-lo num método assíncrono eu tenha sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

No lugar de carregar os dados no construtor da página, tente carregar no evento *OnNavigatedTo*(), que é disparado toda vez que entra na página.

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CarregamentoDeContas.IsActive = true;
        // Idealmente é que o carregamento seja assíncrono para a UI não travar
        DataGridDeContas.ItemsSource = await ListaDeContas.ObterContasAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        CarregamentoDeContas.IsActive = false;
    }
}
```

[Page.OnNavigatedTo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto?view=winrt-18362)